# Is there a way to get sparse weights for a feature column?

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am implementing a sparse model using TensorFlow and feature columns. I am wondering is there a way to extract all the sparse weights and add L1/L2 regularization? For optimizers other than FTRL, the L1/L2 can be implemented using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/l1_regularizer

But this is very inefficient since it adds all the weights densely. Is there a way to get all the weights sparsely (i.e. the weights for the nonzero features of a batch) from `tf.feature_column.linear_model`?

Thanks!